# Functions for changing a button's ID, content and class isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
     function click(target) {
       document.getElementById("popup1").className = "popup";
       document.getElementById("black").className = "blackout";
       target.id = "buttonclicked"
     }      
     function pclose() {
       document.getElementById("popup1").className = "popup hidden";
       document.getElementById("popup2").className = "popup hidden";
       document.getElementById("black").className = "blackout hidden";
       document.getElementById("buttonclicked").id = "";
     }
     function place(variable) {
       if (variable == "house") {
         document.getElementById("buttonclicked").className = "containsemoji";
         document.getElementById("buttonclicked").innerHTML = "";
       }
       pclose()
     }
```

```html
<table width="784" height="560" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="containsemoji" onclick="stadium()">️</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
          <td><button class="empty" onclick="click(this)">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="popup1" class="popup hidden">
        <p class="ptitle"> BUILD</p>
        <p class="tagline">Construction zone ready.</p>
        <button class="bemoji bld" onclick="place(house)"></button>
        <p class="product">HOUSE</p>
        <p class="pricetag">$0</p>
        </div>
        <div id="popup2" class="popup hidden">
        <p class="ptitle">️ STADIUM</p>
        <p class="tagline">UNDEFINED batting.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="black" class="blackout hidden" onclick="pclose()"></div>
```

I have the above code on a website I am working on but it isn't working, and I'm not sure what part of it is breaking.

When a button in a table is pressed, it calls a function based on what it contains. These are separate functions, only one of which is displayed here. If it is empty, it calls click(this), which should open the first popup, change its own id to buttonclicked, and turn on an element that covers everything but the popup and its contents in a semi-transparent black box. A button within this popup calls place(house) when clicked, which should change the class of the empty button clicked and change its contents, then close the popup via pclose(). However, currently, the button inside the popup does nothing.

What's going wrong, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does the HTLM for this part  look like? your algorithmic approach is bad, you have to combine css using pseudo elements

Comment: changing the id of an element is a very, very bad idea, there are other ways to disable a button

Comment: I don't want to disable a button, I want to change its contents.

Answer (score 1):

`click` is a native method. Change `click(this)` to `anythingelse(this)`

Comment: On the actual website, it is named something else; it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the class, or id of a tag then you need to use `setAttribute()`.

```
     function click(target) {
       document.getElementById("popup1").setAttribute("class","popup");
       document.getElementById("black").setAttribute("class","blackout");
       target.id = "buttonclicked"
     }      
     function pclose() {
       document.getElementById("popup1").setAttribute("class","popup hidden");
       document.getElementById("popup2").setAttribute("class","popup hidden");
       document.getElementById("black").setAttribute("class"
,"blackout hidden");
       document.getElementById("buttonclicked").setAttribute("id","");
     }
     function place(variable) {
       if (variable == "house") {
         document.getElementById("buttonclicked").setAttribute("class","containsemoji");
         document.getElementById("buttonclicked").innerHTML = "";
       }
       pclose()
     }
```

Comment: Strange, the method I use in my answer works fine on another website I'm making. I'll try yours, but I'm worried it's redundant...

Comment: I tried your method, and it does the same thing as mine, for the most part. It does seem to lag a bit more when pressing a button in the grid, but otherwise, there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the beginning of an answer concerning the correct way to code this.
Your question is missing too much for me to give you a more complete answer,
such as the meaning of classes - `popup` - `blackout` - `hidden` -
the interaction with the `#popup1` `#popup1` `#black` elements,
and the logic for calling the `place(variable)` function and its argument that can have the value `'house'`

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('table#my-table ')

for (let r=0;r<5;++r)
  {
  let newRow = myTable.insertRow()
  for (let c=0; c<7; ++c) newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = '<button></button>'
  }
myTable.rows[2].cells[3].querySelector('button').className = 'staduim'

myTable.onclick = evt =>
  {
  let clicElm = evt.target
  if (!clicElm.matches('button')) return // reject any click elsewhere tha a button

  if (clicElm.matches('button.staduim')) 
    {
    // do staduim function
    }
  else if (clicElm.classList.toggle('house'))
    {
    popup1.classList.remove('hidden')
    }
  }
popup1.onclick = () => 
  {
  popup1.classList.add('hidden')
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
.hidden {
  display : none;
}
div#popup1,
div#popup2 {
  position : fixed;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  background-color: #dc143c66;
}
table#my-table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 3em auto;
  }
table#my-table td {
  text-align : center;
  border     : none;
  }
table#my-table button {
  width  : 3em;
  margin : .2em;
  }
table#my-table button::before {
  content: '-'
  }
table#my-table button.staduim::before {
  content: '️'
  }
table#my-table button.house::before {   
  content: ''
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>

<div id="popup1" class="hidden">.... ?? ??</div>
```

Comment: Tried this code on its own, and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @DragonSlayr15001  what do you mean by "doesn't seem to do anything." ? did you click on the "Run code snippet" button?
  And why don't you answer my questions in my post?

Comment: My apologies, I copied the code to an external website that runs this sort of code and it didn't do anything, Actually nothing. But it seems to work... decently here via 'Run code snippet', though I can only assume it is because I didn't put the popups in my post. I'll get right on that. As for any other questions you might have, try asking them before complaining that I didn't answer them.

Comment: @DragonSlayr15001 didn't you read my answer head ? ::"Your question is missing too much for me to give you a more complete answer,
such as the meaning of classes - popup - blackout - hidden -
the interaction with the #popup1 #popup1 #black elements,
and the logic for calling the place(variable) function and its argument that can have the value 'house'" . :: and it's rather the opposite, you ask for features that you have not described   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask